# Here SDK - Android Navigate Edition - Could I check if a coordinate is valid?

Tags: here-api

We tried to migrate Here SDK from Premium Edition to Navigate Edition.
And there is a method to check the validity of a coordinate in Coordinate class in Premium Edition.
But we can not find such as the method in Navigate Edition.

I have tried to seach the methods in GeoCoordinates class in Navigate Edition.
But I can not find it.

I wish I could confirm the validity of a coordinate before I used the coordinate.
How can we do that in Navigate Edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this check on your own: If the latitude is in the range [-90, 90] and longitude in the range [-180, 180] it can be considered to be valid.

At least, a formal validity check is not offered (yet) for the new 4.x HERE SDK platform.